# Utilizar uma variável como nome de um arquivo em C

Tags: c, string, arquivo, loop

Estou utilizando a função `system("pathping xxx.xxx.xxx > c:\i.txt")` para deixar o programa fazendo testes de `pathping` e salvando o resultado em um arquivo para analisar posteriormente.

Basicamente queria jogar essa função dentro de um *loop* infinito para ficar sempre analisando porem não consegui encontrar uma maneira de no lugar de `i.txt` utilizar a variável `i`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){

   int i=0;

   while(i>=0){
      system("pathping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx > i.txt");
      i++;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa [formatar a *string*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) para colocar o valor da variável dentro dela. Até dá para fazer concatenando *string*, mas é gambiarra*.

Eu não faria um *loop* infinito, apenas um bem grande. Não é para ter problemas de performance ou de memória, mas haverá problemas quando passar de 2 bilhões e pouco e teria que tratar isso, aí já começa complicar o algoritmo, e se for para complicar, nem é para fazer nada disto.

Se precisa de um número maior, use um `long`ou `long long` no lugar do `int`, com [seu devido limite](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < INT_MAX) {
        char buffer[100] = "";
        sprintf(buffer, "pathping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx > %d.txt\n", i++);
        system(buffer);
    }
}
```

[Fiz um **ideone**](https://ideone.com/heUVWo) ligeiramente modificado porque não tenho permissão de executar o ´system()`. E sim, ele é perigoso. E [coloquei no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/nprromak-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/SaveString.c).

Talvez dar um tempo ([*sleep*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thrd_sleep) ou *timer*) entre um passo e outro seja um boa ideia.

Comment: Exatamente isso que buscava! Obrigado! Apesar de ser um loop infinito acredito que não vai chegar na casa dos bilhões mas vlw pela dica!

Answer (score -3):

Loop infinto você pode colocar:

```
while(true){
    system("pathping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx > i.txt");  
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Obs.: Não me responsabilizo por possíveis problemas de performance e memória.